# Want to pause the autoplay carousel?

Tags: react-hooks

Have written code for image carousel in react hooks. plan to implement carousel without using library . I have successfully implement left arrow, right arrow and Autoplay. But I don't know how to pause the Autoplay while I click on the carousel slide on the image .  Have included my code below. Can you please guide me to do this. Here is my code.

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
 import { departmentSlides } from "../../../components/common/Constants";
function Department() {
  let [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState(0); 
  let departmentSlide = departmentSlides[currentPosition]; 
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      currentPosition !== departmentSlides.length - 1 // Check index length
        ? setCurrentPosition(currentPosition + 1)
        : setCurrentPosition((currentPosition = 0));
    }, 12000);
    return () => clearTimeout(interval);
  });

  const goRight = () => {
    currentPosition !== departmentSlides.length - 1 // Check index length
      ? setCurrentPosition(currentPosition + 1)
      : setCurrentPosition((currentPosition = 0));
  };

  const goLeft = () => {
    currentPosition !== 0 // Check index length
      ? setCurrentPosition(currentPosition - 1)
      : setCurrentPosition((currentPosition = departmentSlides.length - 1));
  };

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      {/* <div className="carousel"> */}
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-12">
          <img
            src={departmentSlide.src}
            className="img-responsive department-img"
            alt="images"
          />
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-xl-8">
              <div className="department-content">
                <h2 className="title text-sm-12 text-md-12 text-xs-12 text-xl-12 text-lg-12">
                  {departmentSlide.title}
                </h2>
                <p className="text text-sm-12 text-md-12 text-xs-12 text-xl-12 text-lg-12">
                  {departmentSlide.text}
                </p>

                <div className="know">
                  <a
                    className="btn btn-white p-4"
                    role="button"
                    href={departmentSlide.link}
                  >
                    KNOW MORE
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="arrow d-flex">
              <button className="" onClick={goLeft} style={{ outline: "none" }}>
                <i className="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
              </button>
              <button
                className=""
                onClick={goRight}
                style={{ outline: "none" }}
              >
                <i className="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Department;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, build state of `autoPlay` and set the value to `true` and use the function `setTimeOut` instead of `setInterval`.

Change the value of `autoPlay` to `false` by clicking on the carousel slider on the image.

Use an `if` condition to check the value of `autoPlay` and if it has `false` value, use the `clearTimeout` method to stop AutoPlay.

```
function Department() {
  let [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState(0); 
  let departmentSlide = departmentSlides[currentPosition];
    
  //First build state of autoPlay and set value to true
  const [autoPlay, setAutoPlay] = useState(true); 
     
  useEffect(() => {
    // use setTimeOut instead of setInterval
    const interval = setTimeOut(() => {
      currentPosition !== departmentSlides.length - 1 // Check index length
        ? setCurrentPosition(currentPosition + 1)
        : setCurrentPosition((currentPosition = 0));
    }, 12000);
    //use if condition to checkout value of autoPlay
    if (autoPlay === false) {
        clearTimeout(interval)
    }
  });
    
  const goRight = () => {
    // change Value of autoPlay to false
    setAutoPlay(false);
    
    currentPosition !== departmentSlides.length - 1 // Check index length
      ? setCurrentPosition(currentPosition + 1)
      : setCurrentPosition((currentPosition = 0));
  };
    
  const goLeft = () => {
    // change Value of autoPlay to false
    setAutoPlay(false);
    currentPosition !== 0 // Check index length
      ? setCurrentPosition(currentPosition - 1)
      : setCurrentPosition((currentPosition = departmentSlides.length - 1));
  };
}
```